# How can the universe's disorder (entropy) be increasing if energy is becoming more uniformly spread?

Tags: energy, cosmology, entropy

It's often said that the entropy of universe is increasing and that the universe's energy is becoming more evenly distributed.  But intuitively, we say also that entropy is a measure of the disorder.

Isn't it a contradiction to say that the universe is becoming both more evenly distributed and more disordered?

Comment: On a macroscopic scale, entropy as a measure of increasing disorder of the universe has started falling out of favor to entropy as a measure of increasing uniformity of the distribution of energy in the universe. The two are consistent with one another. The former is "what does that even mean?" The latter is "so that's what entropy is!"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a common source of confusion because many folks figure that a uniform distribution would be very ordered.

The thing's that things *aren't* becoming uniformly distributed; that's just a macroscopic view!  What's actually happening is that the macroscopic view is becoming increasingly less informative, i.e. uncorrelated with the information of the system.  By the time complete macroscopic uniformity is reached, the observer has completely lost their ability to guess what actually exists at any given point in that space.

For example, consider a glass of water with a block of salt to be dropped into it.  Once the salt is dropped into the water, it'll dissolve and evenly spread around.  That seems more ordered and uniform, huh?  But, it's not!

- Before mixing, you could say if there was a water particle or salt particle at some randomly selected point in the glass.
- As mixing occurs, the amount of information you have about relative probabilities of whether there's a salt particle or water particle at any given point become less certain, though you can still make a better-than-no-information guess at the odds.
- After complete mixing, you have no idea beyond saying that there's a single probability throughout the glass equal to the portion of the particles of the selected type.

This is, the structure (order) that existed before mixing has now been broken down into random chaos.  And that's pure entropy.

Comment: thanks for your correction of traduction and your answer ... it seems you do the analogy with the theory of information and $S= - log I$ with information $I$, don't you ?

Comment: @youpilat13 Sure, though the more general form,$$S~=~-\sum_{{\forall}i}{p_i \ln{\left( p_i \right)}} \,,
$$tends to be more appropriate in the general case since the reduced version requires equal probabilities (which makes stuff like the water-and-salt example confusing, since equal portions of salt won't typically dissolve in water - at least not for sodium chloride).

Comment: ok, it's easier to understand with the notion of information than with classical possible combinations of arranging a system, I have to study more the relation between both to grasp subtilities. thanks

Comment: @youpilat13 Definitely - and just a head's up, one of the biggest misconceptions folks have about entropy is believing that it's a property of a system, but it's not.  Instead, entropy is a property of a model, such that it's model-subjective.  It's initially difficult to understand how a value that was originally empirically measured could possibly be observer-subjective even in classical contexts, but once you get that, I think that the rest tends to fall in place.

Comment: @youpilat13 You might even want to read up about password entropy, in the context of cyber security.  Passwords and assumptions about their structures make for a great simplified case to consider.  Ditto for discussions on "_true_"-vs.-pseudo-randomness; the _tl;dr_ there is that "_true_" randomness is a nonsense concept, though attempting to narrow down where it might possibly exist (and finding that to be an empty space) can be a pretty helpful exercise.

Comment: -@Nat just a last question, I don't understand very well this phrase in answer : "After complete mixing, you have no idea beyond saying that there's a single probability throughout the glass equal to the portion of the particles of the selected type." Could you be more explicit or simplier please about this affirmation ? regards

Comment: @youpilat13 You have a $5\mathrm{g}$ cube of $\text{NaCl}$ that you drop into a $1000\mathrm{mL}$ glass of water.  The cube of salt immediately falls to the bottom of the glass of water, before it starts to significantly dissolve.  At this moment in time, you have pure water in one part of the glass and pure salt in another.  If you consider a point within the glass of water, $\left(x,y,z\right)$, you could tell if there were a particle of water or a particle of salt at that particular point.  [...]

Comment: [...]  After mixing starts, the water phase becomes to include salt, while the solid phase becomes more saturated with water and decrease in size.  Still, you can generally say that the water phase is still mostly water, while the salt phase is still mostly salt.  You can't be sure, but the odds are in that direction.  Until, upon complete mixing, you can say nothing more about any point $\left(x_i,y_i,z_i\right)$ to distinguish it from any other point $\left.\left(x_j,y_j,z_j\right)\right|_{i{\neq}j}$.  [...]

Comment: [...]  For all points For all points $\left(x_i,y_i,z_i\right)$, you pretty much just know that the odds of there being a water particle in that location are about $\frac{1000}{1000+5}$ (ignoring all sorts of conversion factors, activities, ionic strength, etc., for simplicity) while the odds of there being a salt particle are $\frac{5}{1000+5}$.  If you calculate the entropy of this state,$$S~=~-\sum_{{\forall}i}{p_i \ln{\left(p_i\right)}}\,,$$it should be maximized here.

Comment: -@Nath, by considering $S=-p_{1}log(p_{1})-(1-p_{1})log(1-p_{1})$ and calculate $p_{1}$ such $\partial S/\partial p_{1} = 0$, I found $S=S_{max}$ for $p_{1}=0.5$, does that corroborates the affirmation "it should be maximized here" ?

Comment: @youpilat13 Yes, that sounds like an approach to optimizing $S$ by varying $p_1$ to show equilibrium probabilities being predicted by entropy maximization for a process with two states with probabilities $p_1$ and $p_2=1-p_1$.

Comment: -@Nat thanks, that's what I was wondering, entropy is maximum since there are equal probabilities between 2 states, so a maximum of uncertainty or like a minimum of information to locate salt or water particle at given point

Comment: -@Nat I read again your answer above about $S~=~-\sum_{{\forall}i}{p_i \ln{\left(p_i\right)}}$ and you said : "**it should be maximized**" : what do you mean by saying that ? **the entropy is maximized with equal-probabilities**, this is not the case by taking $\frac{5}{1000+5}$ and $\frac{1000}{1000+5}$ probabilities for two states ? sorry my english is not perfect, if you could clarify the expression "it should be maximized here", this would be fine. Regards

Answer (score 1):

No, it's not a contradiction. Entropy is not a measure of disorder. The entropy $S$ is a measure of the number of ways to arrange a system,

$$ S = k\ln\Omega. $$

The energy is becoming more "evenly spread" *because* the entropy has to increase, for this is the most probable macrostate.

There are more ways to arrange evenly-distributed energy than there are to arrange the energy if all of it is concentrated in a single place.

Comment: @zhutcgens1 So, where does this definition of "measure of disorder" come from ? it is just a microscopic point of view ?

Comment: I would strongly contest that "measure of disorder" is a potential **definition** of entropy.  Its relationship comes from multiplicity $\Omega$; sometimes, disorder and multiplicity can have similar meanings. Like, if you have a messy bedroom, there are more ways to arrange your things because they are disordered. But extending this as "definition" is too far.

Comment: This youtube, MIT course, confirms that entropy is the measure of number of ways to arrange a system. Very interesting and great graphics.  https://youtu.be/870y6GUKbwc